# My code is throwing errors, I have written in using kivy python. Its giving an error of invalid property name in the kv file and and also in kv file

Tags: python, mobile, kivy, kivy-language

```
#This is the main file where I declared the property objects  
nationalid = ObjectProperty(None)
firstname = ObjectProperty(None)
lastname = ObjectProperty(None)
PhoneNumber = ObjectProperty(None)
age = ObjectProperty(None)
Nationality = ObjectProperty(None)
Gender = ObjectProperty(None)
password = ObjectProperty(None)
conpassword = ObjectProperty(None)
```

''' This the kivy file where it is displaying errors '''

```
<CreateAccountWindow>:
name: "create"
nationalid = idNo
firstname = fname
lastname = lname
Phonenumber = phoneno
age = age
Nationality = nationality
Gender = gender
password = passw
conpassword = conpassw
```

'''It's outputting the following error message:'''
2: name: "create"
3:
4: nationalid = idNo
5: firstname = fname
6: lastname = lname
...
Invalid property name

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question is very long and not very specific. Please provide [Minimum, Reproducable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Error in the .kv file... Error invalid property name

Comment: I would like to help you, but your question is incredibly unclear. First of all, it's not a question, it should be clear what you are asking of the community. You should provide the error message and where exactly in your code it's originating. And most importantly, you should shorten your code, until only the parts relevant for the questions are left. No one will read 350 lines of unindented code without knowing what they are looking for.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You cannot use `=` for property values in `kv`, you must use `:`.
2. Your indentation is incorrect.

Try changing your `kv` to:

```
<CreateAccountWindow>:
    name: "create"
    nationalid: idNo
    firstname: fname
    lastname: lname
    Phonenumber: phoneno
    age: age
    Nationality: nationality
    Gender: gender
    password: passw
    conpassword: conpassw
```